# Are there organized multiday cave trips in Europe?

Tags: tours, extreme-tourism, caves

Recently i went for a short (1 hour) walk through the caves of [Cocaliere](http://www.grotte-cocaliere.com/) in the ardeche in France. During the very touristic trip, although still quite interesting, we were guided passed two tents, from where the initial explorers searched the surrounding. The idea of being able to explore through a cave for more then one day seems quite tempting and adventurous. Is this possible while not being an experienced speleologist?

Comment: Are you asking about a particular area? There are millions and millions of caves in the world, with over 1600 caves worldwide longer than 3km in length.  The question is very interesting, but as it stands is in danger of being considered too broad.

Comment: (and yes, the answer is  yes, but I really would like a **specific** area of the world before I start my answer)

Comment: That is a promising comment. I first thought that I should be happy if there was only one and I should consider extensive traveling if that was required.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like there are quite a few, with [this page giving a good start](http://www.iexplore.com/activity-guides/caving/top-10-europe).

**Hölloch Caverns, Switzerland**

Hölloch Caverns is the second largest cave system in the world and extends as much as 118 miles in length. There’s a basic touristy, light section, but guided tours and **multi-day expeditions** in the cave for advanced spelunkers are available as well.

**Dan yr Ogof, Wales**

This ten mile long cave system in south Wales is thought to go as far as 150 miles. It’s a major showcave and considered the greatest natural wonder in Britain, but also a favorite site for European cavers.

**Ease Gill, England**

The wide variety of caving routes and a stunning river passage, the main Drain, make this UK cave one of the top in all of Europe for spelunking. The longest system in the British Isles.

Plus others, but these sound like the longest.

[Cumberland Caverns](http://www.cumberlandcaverns.com/adventure_trips.htm) has overnight tours.

Finally you could ask on the [National Spelunking Society site](http://www.caves.org/) - yes it's US, but their cavechat forum has a lot of people who can give suggestsions based on skill and ability.